# Applying a vector field to image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vector, 3d

How do I apply a vector field obtained via quiver, to an image which causes the pixels to displace in the direction of the vectors (image is warped)?

Also, if the vector field I have is 3 dimensional, how would I do this? Think of it as laying down a flat 2 dimensional image over a 3 dimensional terrain. How would I go about viewing this in matlab?

Thank you for your time

EDIT: I have to warp the image not just in the Z axis, but along the X and Y axes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Laying down a flat 2 dimensional image over a 3 dimensional terrain:
[image]

It's not very clear the way the axes are oriented but this is an image of a clown mapped on the peaks function. Exact steps are described in the documentation of [`surface`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surface.html) in the example 'Display image along surface plot.'

```
load clown
C = flipud(X);
figure
surface(XD,YD,ZD,C,...
    'FaceColor','texturemap',...
    'EdgeColor','none',...
    'CDataMapping','direct')
colormap(map)
view(-35,45)
```

Essentially, you create your surface with `CData` as the image you want to be displayed and set an appropriate colormap for the axes.

Comment: The code you wrote to reproduce that plot would be nice.  Even if it's linked in the documentation, the code to reproduce the plot posted here for self-containment would be helpful.  The link you posted may change over time.

Comment: This allows me to deform my image along the Z axis. However, I do have deformations in the X and Y axis as well. How do I perform them?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `imwarp` function in the Image Processing Toolbox.