# How to apply vector field to image in 2D with python?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, matplotlib, computer-vision

I generate two Gaussian Random Fields with the library `FyeldGenerator`. If they are plotted, it's like this:

```
from FyeldGenerator import generate_field
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Helper that generates power-law power spectrum
def Pkgen(n):
    def Pk(k):
        return np.power(k, -n)
    return Pk

# Draw samples from a normal distribution
def distrib(shape):
    a = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=shape)
    b = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=shape)
    return a + 1j * b

shape = (512, 512)

field_x = generate_field(distrib, Pkgen(3), shape)
field_y = generate_field(distrib, Pkgen(3), shape)

plt.imshow(field_x, cmap='seismic')
plt.show()
plt.imshow(field_y, cmap='seismic')
```

[image]

Then I plot with matplotlib with `quiver` the vector field.

[image]

Now I would like to apply on an image of the same size of the random fields, the vector field. I would like the pixel in a point (i,j) to move in the direction (in 2D), which is shown in the quiver function. Is there anyway to do it ?

This is an example of this problem done on matlab, but in 3D :

> Link of stackoverflow : [Applying a vector field to image in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551379/applying-a-vector-field-to-image-in-matlab)
>   [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is the [remap function in opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4).
As described in the link, the function remaps the values based on the indexing arrays mapx and mapy: 
(x,y)=(mapx(x,y),mapy(x,y))

If I understood properly what you would like to do you first need to create the base indexes for the mapx and mapy:

```
mapx_base, mapy_base = np.meshgrid(np.arange(shape[0]), np.arange(shape[1]))
```

Then deform the image indexes with your vector field. Here I multiply to increase the deformation.

```
mapx = mapx_base + field_x*30
mapy = mapy_base + field_y*30
```

Finally resample your image

```
img = cv2.imread('apple.jpg', 0).astype(np.float32)
deformed_apple = cv2.remap(img, mapx.astype(np.float32), mapy.astype(np.float32), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Of course, the field needs to be smoothed if you would like to have a less noisy deformation.

Hope this helps!

[image: apple][image]

Comment: @cthnguyen I'm glad this helped! Please accept the answer to close the topic if everything is clear now. Thanks!